# Displaying ID field in a grid or address bar

Tags: c#, asp.net

What are the pros and cons of displaying your identity field either in your address bar `(http://someapp/Edit.aspx&id=2)` or in gridview in your UI?

Comment: Unless the ID has meaning to the user, I wouldn't show it.   Keep the user view as simple as possible.   If the user might need to reference it for tech support, consider making it a hint text, where you can instruct the user to mouse over a field to get the ID number

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm in displaying ID field provided user know what that ID field means to him. If not, then it will just confuse the user.

For example you have an Employee ID and each employee in an organization uses his ID at multiple places for identification (like username or mail short name etc.) then he is used to know by his ID and if you design an application where in that user see his ID field it would be good.

But in case your have products in your organization and your have given ID to identify them in your system, but the end user, a buyer of those ID isnt aware of them, then it doesnt make sense to show that to them. It will confuse him.

Answer (score 0):

When you display ID in the url, make sure that there is no security issue.  If the user is smart enough and change the Id make sure that they can only see data that they can see.

For Example user A can only see data with id 1,2,3  you need to make sure that if he modify the url and put id 4 he will get access denied message.